# Publishing to WebSphere Application Server v7.0

Tags: jms, websphere

I am using WebSphere Application Server v7.0 with Eclipse helious 3.6.2, it was working smooth previously with my java web projects, but I have just changed the properties of my project using runtime jre6, which was previoursly using jre6 comming with WebSphere as alternate runtime.

Then without testing I again reset my runtime back to runtime in WS. But now server is started quite well, but when I try to publish my project, it throws error and I can't publish it successfully and I am unable to run my project. I am using JMS in my project.

here is the msg:

> Problem Occured: 'Publishing to WebSphere Application Server v7.0 at
>   localhost...' has encountered a problem An internal error occured
>   during: 'Publishing to WebSphere Application Server v7.0 at
>   localhost...'
>
> Details: An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to WebSphere
>   Application Server v7.0 at localhost...".
>
> com/ibm/CORBA/iiop/ORB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forget to edit the eclipse.ini file in eclipse home folder, and changed the vm parameter value back to the 
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\javaw.exe